# $\|f\|^2_{H^{-1}(\mathbb{T})}\lesssim \int_\mathbb{T} |\sin(x)f(x)|^2 \; dx$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, fourier-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have been stuck in this question for a while, and I would appreciate any new ideas. I have been considering the inequality
$$
\|f\|^2_{H^{-1}(\mathbb{T})}\lesssim \int_\mathbb{T} |\sin(x)f(x)|^2 \; dx,
$$
assuming that $\int_\mathbb{T} f(x)=0$.

The inequality has the Fourier series analogue
$$
\sum_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{|f_j|^2}{j^2}\lesssim \sum_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}|f_{j}-f_{j+2}|^2.
$$

A counterexample to the inequality is $f_j=1$ $\forall j$, which is like taking a $f=\delta_0$.

The question is if adding the constraint $\|f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{T})}=1$, the inequality actually holds and which is the optimal constant.

My intuition to why should the inequality hold, is that the singularity of $\sin(x)$ at zero as a weight has the right scaling, as in Caffarelli, Luis, Robert Kohn, and Louis Nirenberg. "First order interpolation inequalities with weights." Compositio Mathematica 53, no. 3 (1984): 259-275.

Comment: How are the $H^{-1}({\mathbb T})$ and $L({\mathbb T})$ norms defined?
(I'm guessing that the constraint "$||f||_L^2(\mathbb{T})=1$"
was meant as $||f||^2_{L(\mathbb{T})}=1$.)

Comment: Sorry that was a bad typo; it meant $L^2(\mathbb{T})$. The $H^{-1}$ is defined in Fourier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality does not hold. This becomes clear if we rewrite the discrete version as
$$
\sum |f_n|^2/n^2 \lesssim \|Lf\|^2 ,
$$
with $(L f)_n=f_{n+1}-f_{n-1}$. Notice that $iL$ is self-adjoint on $\ell^2$ and has spectrum $[-2,2]$ (because it becomes multiplication by $2\sin x$ after taking Fourier transforms, and in fact that is how we got $L$ in the first place).

Now an approximate eigenfunction $f$ of $iL$ for $\lambda=0$ with $f_0=0$ will make the RHS small, but not the LHS.

**Addendum:** Given my discussion with the OP in the comments below, this perhaps deserves to be made more explicit: we can take $f_n=0$ for even $n$ (we were asked to make $f_0=0$) and $f_n\simeq 1$ for odd $n$ on a large interval (we want $Lf\simeq 0$). More precisely, let's let $f_n$ decay linearly on an interval of length $\simeq N$. Then $(Lf)_n\simeq 1/N$, so $\|Lf\|^2\lesssim N\cdot (1/N)^2= 1/N$. However, $\sum |f_n|^2/n^2$ clearly does not get small when $N\to\infty$.

Comment: I will think more about the approximate eigenfunction. With respect to taking a $f$ supported near zero, it would be something like $f=(\epsilon/2)^{1/2} I_{(-\epsilon,\epsilon)}$, which goes to zero as a measure, so the $H^{-1}$ should also.

Comment: I think $f=\epsilon^{-1/2}\chi_{-\epsilon,\epsilon}$ has $H^{-1}$ norm going to zero and that's the catch. It has, for instance, $L^{3/2}$ norm going to zero, which is compactly embedded in $H^{-1}$.

Comment: @Sloth-Meister: You're right, I made some strange claims in the (now deleted) comments, but I hope I've clarified matters now.

Comment: Thanks for the help! But I am still not satisfied, your addendum looks like the counter-example I wrote. As $N$ becomes larger, it converges to $f_j=1$ for $j$ odd. Which doesn't satisfy the condition $||f||_{L^2}=1$. My belief is that by putting the restriction on the $L^2$ norm, one get's rid of being able to converge to something non-trivial which is supported at zero, a.k.a. the $\delta_0$.

Comment: @Sloth-Meister: I think it goes the other way around: if you had your inequality with some constant $C$, then my $f$ from above with a sufficiently large $N$ (how large exactly depends on $C$) will refute it. I only work with compactly supported $f$'s here. (Of course they don't satisfy $\|f\|=1$, but I can normalize.)

Comment: A more abstract way of saying it is that $\|f\|_2=1$ (which is really the same as requiring that $f\in L^2$, by homogeneity) isn't going to help you because these $f$ are dense in $H^{-1}$, so if that worked, then you would get the estimate in general.

Comment: Perhaps I am confused, but in your example the normalization, makes the RHS of order one. You are right that $L^2$ is dense in $H^{-1}$, but if you stay in a bounded set $L^2$, the extrema are still in $L^2$, by the l.s.c. of the norm under weak convergence. That is the whole point of asking for this restriction.

Comment: Yes, if you were restricted to $\|f\|\le 1$ when approximating, then the limit would be in $L^2$. But if you had $\|f\|_{H^{-1}}\le C\|Lf\|$ for $\|f\|_2=1$, then you get it for all $f\in L^2$ and then for all $g\in H^{-1}$ by approximating. It is true that the approximating $f$'s will have $L^2$ norms that diverge to infinity, but that doesn't matter.